# Property "CWebApplication.clientScript" is read only

Tags: php, yii

Contoller

```
   public function actionSend(){
        Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('myplugin');
        $this->render();
       echo 'submit';
   }
```

main.php

```
    'clientScript' =>array(
     'packages'=>array(   

    'myplugin'=>array(                             
        'baseUrl'=>'myload/',
        'js'=>array('myload/bow.js'),
    ),
    'boot'=>array(                       //set others js libraries
        'baseUrl'=>'myload/',
        'js'=>array('myload/bow2.js'),
        'css'=>array(                        // and css
         //   'css/bootstrap.min.css',
         //   'css/custom.css',
         //   'css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css',
        ),
        'depends'=>array('myplugin'),         // cause load myplugin before load this.
    )
         ) )
```

Error:

**Property "CWebApplication.clientScript" is read only.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must put `clientScript` inside `components` like:

```
'components'=>array(    
   'clientScript' => array(    
      //something depend on your configure
   ),    
),
```

Besides, this link is useful for you: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/1421-where-to-put-javascript-file/